# How to clear Path2D from canvas

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas

I am trying to make an animation by rendering Path2D into canvas in a loop.
I need to clear or edit existing Path2D and put new one every few seconds. I have tried clearRect() method but it seems to not do anything. Here's my code:

```
update(options) {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.nativeElement.innerWidth, this.canvas.nativeElement.innerHeight);
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    const path = this.cardinal(options.points, true, 1); // SVG path
    const P2D = new Path2D(path);
    this.ctx.fill(P2D);
}
```

How to clear the path or maybe edit existing one?

FIX:

```
this.canvas.nativeElement.width, this.canvas.nativeElement.height
```

have been returning undefined. I had to use .width and .height properties of the canvas to make it work.

Comment: add a console.log(this.canvas.nativeElement.innerWidth) and check this. Is this returning the right val. let us know. else create a fiddle.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineTo - you can check this link here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, once something has been painted onto canvas it will stay there. If you want to change one thing you need to repaint the whole.

And about the `clearRect` - the 3rd and 4th arguments shouldn't be the actual size of canvas node but rather it's resolution, i.e. it's width and height attribute, in your case: `this.canvas.width` and `this.canvas.height`

Comment: Yep, it turned out innerWidth/Height was returning undefined. Thanks, all working like a charm! I have updated my answer with your solution :)